# JSHint Error : This character may get silently deleted by one or more browsers

Tags: jshint, node-modules, ember-cli, broccolijs

line 1, col 0, This character may get silently deleted by one or more browsers.
I get this error 4 times, for every .js file I've added.

For instance

error text:

> 'scripts/models/company.js: line 1, col 0, This character may get
>   silently deleted by one or more browsers '

scripts/models/company.js content:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
address: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: What version of JSHint are you using? That message is no longer given in the more recent versions. The fact that it's being given at that position means it's likely you have some non-printable character before the first actual character in your file.

Comment: @JamesAllardice, I use ember-cli (v 0.0.33) and it uses broccoli-jshint v 0.5.0 (v 2.5.1 - jshint).

Comment: I've updated it to the last version (V 2.5.1), but still get the same errors

Comment: Not sure if this is related but 'int' is not one of the Ember Data datatypes. The built in data types are string, number, boolean and date.

Comment: I removed this type, but error still occurs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This character is the UTF-8 BOM ([Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)), nothing to worry about. Just open the file in Notepad++ or another editor and change the encoding from 'UTF-8' to 'UTF-8 without BOM'.

Comment: Mac users: TextEdit by default saves the file in “UTF-8 without BOM” encoding.